# Screws required to attach HD's to mounting tray for Apple Mac Pro Tower Mid-2012

Tags: mac-pro, hardware

I recently ordered 2 new HD's for my Apple Mac Pro Tower however on opening my Mac, I found all the screws were missing in the last two trays.  I borrowed as many as I could from the other two trays but I need more!  However I cannot find them for sale anywhere!  I can only find them for sale with the mounting trays for e.g £15.  I need about 6-10.

Also they seem to be attached to some grey rubber too.  Is this important?

What do I need to consider if I want to buy replacements?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are talking about the first generation MacPro "CheeseGrater" tower. *for future reference it is best to include the model number with your question so there is no confusion.*

The screws are actually standard threads and common to **ANY** hard drive. You should be able to get these screws at any hardware store worth its name. Just take the HD with you to make sure you get the right ones.

The rubber grommets can also be sourced at a hardware or electrical parts store. Just get some grommets that will fit in the holes in the Apple HD trays and then size the screws long enough to span the gap between the grommet, the HD tray and into the drive. Depending on the size of the screw head you may also need some flat washers.

I did this with my MacPro 1,1 many years ago and it worked a treat.

Sourcing the Apple genuine parts proved frustrating and the few places/people that carried them wanted way more money than it was worth. In total you should be able to get screws, grommets and washers for well under $10

Comment: Many thanks! I didn't know how to get the model number, I could only find the serial number which I didn't think would be helpful.

Comment: I will do as you say & take the screw & tray to a hardware/electrical store & see if I can match it with your suggestions.

Comment: Is the grommet necessary for static reasons or just to make the screws secure?

Comment: They are there for vibration isolation and for the drives to line up properly on the trays. You could probably use a washer or two if you like.